# Python3 reading USB joystick

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, joystick

I am very green to python and python3. Most of my background has come from microprocessor work such as arduinos and basic stamp.

So I am writing something for being able to control an IP camera from a joystick. Plan is to use something like a Pi to run the code. The program will read a usb joystick in and convert it into an URL for the cameras API. i have got this far but with an issue.

the code with be run on a linux os proberly ubuntu or raspbian

I have got so far and seem to be working well apart from a snag that I have come across with the bit of code I am using to read the joystick.

this is just a snippet of the rest of the code

```
import sys

pipe = open('/dev/input/js0', 'rb') #open joystick 
action = []
while True:
    StickValue = readStik(pipe)
    print ("StickValue")

    def readStick(pipe):
        action = []
        while stop == 1:
            for character in pipe.read(1):
                action += [int(character)]
                if len(action) == 8:
                    StickValue = action
                    action = []
                    stop = 2
                    ##when joystick is stationary code hangs here.
                    return  StickValue


#do some more stuff here while waiting for new joystick inputs apposed to hanging
```

I can see why it hangs as its waiting till all 8bytes have been read out before stopping the while loop but am struggling to working out how I get around it or is there a better way of reading the joystick. I have been looking at pygame now but would mean a major re write of the rest of the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off buffering by adding `buffering=0` to the `open` call.